# NetBeans8.0.2でのGoogle App Engine for PHPの設定について

Tags: php, google-app-engine, netbeans

NetBeans8.0.2を使用しています。OSはMac OS X 10.10.3です。

Google App Engine for PHPを使用するため[サービス]-[サーバー]で
ステップ１.サーバーを選択・・・Google App Engine
としたのですが、次の
ステップ２.Server Locationになにを入力すればいいのかわかりません。

```
/usr/local/google_appengine
```

や

```
/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine
```

を入力しても

> Provide a valid Google App Engine Location

と出たままで次のステップへ進めません。

Google App Engine for PHPは
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads
からMac用の1.9.21をダウンロードしています。

NetBeansのプラグインは
https://code.google.com/p/nb-gaelyk-plugin/downloads/list
から

```
nbappengine-7.4.x-gae1.8.x-3.0.2.zip
```

をダウンロードし

```
org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-appengine-deployment.nbm
org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-appengine-editor.nbm
org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-appengine-hints.nbm
org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-appengine-kit.nbm
org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-appengine-samples.nbm
org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-appengine.nbm
```

をインストール済みです。

ちなみにGoogleAppEngineLauncherからは問題なくデプロイできています。

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

ちょっと、NetBeansを触ったことが無いので想像でしかありませんが、
EUかUSでは無いでしょうか？